# Modify seaborn plot with double-sided y-axis

Tags: python, seaborn

I am creating a plot like this.

[image]

Now I would like to add information about the gap to this [plot](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/8265539575953-What-is-the-MIPGap). This gap can be in the interval of [0%, 100%]. I would now also like to include this in my plot, whereby the values of the "Gap in %" should then be visible on the right-hand side of the plot. Something like this. How do I achieve this with my code?

```
def plot(vals):
    sns.set(style='darkgrid')
    sns.scatterplot(x=list(range(len(vals))), y=vals, marker='o')
    sns.lineplot(x=list(range(len(vals))), y=vals)
    plt.xlabel('Iterations')
    plt.xticks(range(0, len(vals)))
    plt.ylabel('Objective function value')
    title = "Title"
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()
    
data = [21.000000000110038, 13.784000000010213, 9.665913140823003, 9.487000000497686]
gap = [54.8238095, 31.1376812, 1.8444649, 0.0]

plot(data)
```